# WinUI and WiX installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, winui-3

Can we use WiX toolset to create a installer for a WinUI app? I've found documentation for creating an installer for Windows Forms project but is it possible for a WinUI app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely. WinUI applications are just files, shortcuts and the such like any other application.

Comment: This question might not be that straight forward.  I'm still a WPF guy so I'm not sure what project type he's talking about.  In VS2022 project templates I searched for WinUI and Maui came up saying it was various platforms including WinUI.  After digging in I found out that it can only do MSIX deployment.  At https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/overview it says ".NET MAUI currently only allows publishing an MSIX package. You can't yet publish a Windows executable file for distribution."

Comment: This page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/deploy-unpackaged-apps is more optimistic for other project types.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/package-and-deploy/self-contained-deploy/deploy-self-contained-apps

Comment: That's because they are pushing MSIX in the docs. You can install with an MSI as well. Besides, WIX can build both MSI and MSIX today. Pick your installation technology. WiX can get you there. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using this project template:

[image]

I added/changed these properties

```
<EnableMsixTooling>false</EnableMsixTooling>
<WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>
```

I was able to build and run the exe.  However when I tried to create a publish profile:

[image]

The app fails to start and in Event Viewer I see:

```
Faulting application name: App1.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x65180e9d
Faulting module name: Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll, version: 3.1.3.0, time stamp: 0xbfd77fd2
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x00000000007e5d6a
Faulting process id: 0x0x4E5C
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1D9FCC088F82193
Faulting application path: C:\1\Test\App1\App1\bin\win10-arm64\publish\App1.exe
Faulting module path: C:\1\Test\App1\App1\bin\win10-arm64\publish\Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll
Report Id: 7b83068d-8606-4d4c-9139-f787771a1739
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

This is strange because .net sdk projects are supposed to be published not built.  Anyways if the files from the build can be xcopied to another machine and ran then WiX can surely do the job.